How to impose sign restriction in VAR with Stata?
I was trying to impose sign restrictions in my VAR analysis with Stata. Codes are as follows:
var cpi0 gdp0 g200 ex0 int0 un0 cro0 ener0 ukr1, lags(1 2 3) **the VAR model, 9 variables included
var_nr sr, varname("v") opt("opts") **use sign restrictions
var_nr_options_display , optname("opts") all **take a look at the options

var_nr_shock_create, var("v") sr("sr1")
var_nr_shock_name, labels("cpis", "gdps", "g20s", "exs", "ints", "unems", "cros", "eners", "ukrs") sr("sr1")

var_nr_shock_set, sr("sr1") shock("cro0") affecting("gdp0") start(1) neg **claim the sign restrictions
var_nr_shock_set, sr("sr1") shock("cro0") affecting("g200") start(1) pos **claim the sign restrictions
var_nr_shock_set, sr("sr1") shock("cro0") affecting("un0") start(1) pos **claim the sign restrictions
var_nr_shock_set, sr("sr1") shock("cro0") affecting("cro0") start(1) pos **claim the sign restrictions

var_nr_sign_restrict, var("v") sr("sr1") opt("opts") out("out1") **the restricted VAR

Then the erro appears:
sign_restrict():  3498  4000 iterations attempted without success. Try different sign restrictions.

I am not sure whether it is because of my bad coding or it is because my restrictions are wrong.
I tried to impose only one restriction, and the codes ran well, but the results of impulse responses were completely blank, so I guess something went wrong with the codes.

My guess is quite different. You asked for a solution that Stata can't find. Whether your request is reasonable and achievable depends on the data and your goals, which lie a long way from what can be discussed here. You are likely to get much better advice on Statalist, Stack Overflow is an enormous community, but very few people watch the Stata tag.
